# I need to execute a css animation and a Url.Action at the same time

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, asp.net-mvc

as I mentioned above, I need to know if there is an option that can provide an execution of an "Url.Action" and a CSS animation at the same time?

```
<div style="zoom: 0.2">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div id="ms-container">
            <label for="ms-download">
                <div class="ms-content">
                    <div class="ms-content-inside">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="ms-download" 
                         onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("DownloadDirectory", "Home", new 
                         { @class = "btn btn-success}, null)';return false;" />
                            <div class="ms-line-down-container">
                                <div class="ms-line-down"></div>
                            </div>
                        <div class="ms-line-point"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `Html.Action()` just returns a string URL to a resource - do you mean that you want to show an animation when you click a link? Also, there is no reference to `Html.Action()` in your code...? Your question as it stands is unclear.

Comment: Im sorry I meant "Url.Action" instead of "Html.Action"

Comment: No worries, my comment still applies.

Comment: I want to show an animation while I perform the "Url.Action()"-Method

Comment: If you click a link to go to a new page (via an `a` element with the `src` set using a `Url.Action()` call), then the page will be unloaded so you cannot run any animation.

Comment: we don't load a new page, we just call a ActionResult, there we provide a file to download, and refer back to the old page. Is it possible in this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a CSS animation to an element when the checkbox is checked using jQuery. Your HTML onClick will run, and the JS function will run alongside it, adding and removing the animation class to whatever element you want based on whether or not the checkbox is checked.

```
function doAnimation(){
  //if the box is checked
  if ($('#ms-download').prop('checked')){
    //add the class with the animation
    $('#whateverElement').addClass('class-with-animation')
    //if unchecked, remove animation class
  } else {
    $('#whateverElement').removeClass('class-with-animation')
  }
}
```

With Vanilla JavaScript:

```
function doAnimation(){
  //if the box is checked
  if (document.getElementById('ms-download').checked){
    //add the class with the animation
    document.querySelector('whateverElement').classList.add('class-with-animation')
    //if unchecked, remove animation class
  } else {
    document.querySelector('whateverElement').classList.remove('class-with-animation')
  }
}
```